# Can not find script file "C:\res\windows\zip.js" in Phonegap (windows)

Tags: android, node.js, phonegap-build

Thought of trying phonegap today.

- Installed Node.js
- installed phonegap using command:

  ```
   npm install -g phonegap
  ```
- created app using

  ```
  phonegap create my-app
  ```
- running command

  ```
  phonegap run android
  ```
- got this error - Can not find script file "C:\res\windows\zip.js"

Not sure what's happening. I have tried downloading zip.js and placing inside www\js as well as build. Not sure why the error is referring to res folder while there isn't any.

Anyone faced similar situation ?

Comment: Facing the same issues here. Trying phonegap for the first time and really not making much progress due to this error

Comment: I'm getting the same error when running phonegap run ios, do you too?

Answer (score 5):

I was able to get rid of the error by updating Phonegap:

```
npm update -g phonegap
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see Github issue with the same probmlem -> https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-cli/issues/81

or here -> https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-cli/issues/77

You should go to the app directory:

```
$ cd my-app/
$ phonegap build android
```

Comment: I'm running the command from the 'my-app' dir, yet it still displays the error that it can't find the js file. In my case, it is trying to look in my C:\Users\MyUser\res\windows directory. This seems to be the parent from where I run the command

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and found a solution!

Solution:

- Insure you've installed the Java JDK and Android SDK (I installed the Android SDK through Android Studio)
- Install [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) (core of PhoneGap). Because I'm not sure if you can run the cordova commands without installign cordova seperatly.
- Now the reason why your commands weren't working: after `phonegap create my-app`, the PhoneGap CLI doesn't create a folder for the Android platform. Thus when running the command: `phonegap run android`, the android platform is'nt present in the PhoneGap project. To solve this issue just run the following command: `cordova platform add android` (in the my-app folder)
- Then build: `phonegap local build android`, and the Android app will successfully compiled.

Easier alternatives:

- [PhoneGap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/): It is a cloud-based service who removes the need for different SDKs to build the application for different platforms. It is a free service as long that your applications are open-source, or you limit your private apps to just one.
- Develop the application with your beloved edittor/IDE and run the application with the [Desktop app](http://phonegap.com/blog/2015/03/02/phonegap-app-desktop-0-1-2/), who runs a local server connecting with the application which you can download at the application stores.
- Just Build/run the application in the platforms' IDE. In case of Android, use Android studio to build en deploy the application on your device. (Open the platforms->Android project in your IDE)